# Django printed list displays blank fields

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am trying to print a list of values from a database onto a html page using Django.

I have a model defined as:

```
class Drink(models.Model):
    drink_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    strength = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.drink_name
```

A view defined as:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from .models import Drink

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    served_drinks = Drink.objects.order_by('strength')
    context = {'served_drinks': served_drinks}
    return render(request, 'tavern/index.html', context)
```

And a template:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
Welcome to the tavern.<br><br>
{% if served_drinks %}
    <ul>
    {% for drink in served_drinks %}
        <li>{{ Drink.drink_name }} with a strength of {{ Drink.strength }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No drinks are available.</p>
{% endif %}

{{served_drinks}}

</html>
```

When the template runs is generates:

```
Welcome to the tavern.

with a strength of
with a strength of
with a strength of
with a strength of

<QuerySet [<Drink: Water>, <Drink: Wine>, <Drink: Ale>, <Drink: Black Ale>]>
```

I get a line for each item, but no drink_name. When I return the template tag `{{served_drinks}}` I can see the items there, so I assume something is wrong with my line:
`<li>{{ Drink.drink_name }} with a strength of {{ Drink.strength }}</li>`

Why does `{{ Drink.drink_name }}` not return the name of the drink in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have typo with variable name. `Drink` should be `drink`.

```
{% for drink in served_drinks %}
        <li>{{ Drink.drink_name }} with a strength of {{ Drink.strength}}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Corrected code,

```
{% for drink in served_drinks %}
        <li>{{ drink.drink_name }} with a strength of {{ drink.strength}}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Aha, so simple - thank you for your help! I was obviously trying to refer to the model field, not the loop, oops!